# Which of these is considered better design? (break before yield or check, yield and break if check is negative)

Tags: python, design-patterns

Hope it's not been asked before, which one of these is considered better / faster / more 'pythonic'?
break after check:

```
while True:
    #returns either a `page` or None
    p += 1
    page = self.page_has_articles(p) 
    if page:
        yield page
    else:
        break
```

or first check and break:

```
while True:
    p += 1
    page = self.page_has_articles(p)
    if not page:
        break
    yield page
```

Comment: "Better" is subjective and is therefore a bit off-topic for SO. Are you able to modify your post to ask a question that can be objectively answered? If not, you may want to consider asking this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com .

Comment: What do *you* think is more readable?

Comment: FWIW, this is one reason why I always with python had a `until` clause of some sort ... but it is what it is.

Comment: @mgilson: that's the one disadvantage of using indentation as a block delimiter; you cannot have constructs that require a loop controlling statement at the *end* of the block. Hence, we use `while` and live with it. :-)

Comment: In the case of this small example it doesn't really matter, in the case of having more code before yielding, I would definitely take the *first check and break* approach because it gets rid of an indentation level and clearly shows the break at the top.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yeah.  I've never been able to tackle the semantics of something like that either...(though I have thought about it).  Using indentation as a block delimiter is one of my biggest complaints about python for the same reasons that Bryan Oakley brings up in this answer and comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1995278/748858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the (small) example given there is no clear difference between the two on first glance. However if we take an approach of *error early* or *return early*. It is clearly better to do the `break` and any cleaning up first.

This gets even clearer when the code used increases in line count. When reading code it is easier to take a mental note of `if there is no page, we break` than `if there is a page, we do this, and if it isn't, we break`.

So for sake of readability on (larger) blocks of code the approach of using `break` early has an advantage (in my opinion).

Comment: Makes good sense to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools` to do you dirty work instead of rolling your own loop.

```
import itertools as it

def enumerate_pages(self,start_p):
    return it.takewhile(bool,it.imap(self.page_has_articles,it.count(start_p,1)))
```

`takewhile`, `imap`, and `count` all return **iterable** objects, so will work just as your while loops given as example in your question.

`it.count(start_p,1)` iterates from `start_p` with a step of 1.

`it.imap()` performs just like `map()` in python 2.x, but returns an `iterable` instead of a `list`.

`it.takewhile()` stops iteration at the first element to return `False` from the given predicate function, which in this case is `bool()`