# Advantage of using parentheses within returned valriable

Tags: javascript

Sometimes i see this in web tutorials:

```
/**
 * Just for example
 */
function getConstructor() {

    /**
     * Constructor fn, that will be returned by 'getConstructor' fn
     */
    function SomeTypeConstructor() {
        // some code
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // And here is the question!
    // What is this parentheses for?
    return( SomeTypeConstructor );
}
```

Can anyone say what is this parentheses for?

Comment: A matter of taste. Though some people could be using it as a reminder about [automatic semicolon insertion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2003277/1233508).

Answer (score 0):

Since `return` is a statement, and not a method, parentheses are not necessary.