# Uncaught Syntax error: unexpected token ( even though function is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a web application.  I have a task controller in  a separate .js file which I include in the main .html file:

```
<head>
  <script src = "tasks-controller.js"></script>
</head>
```

and the file tasks-controller.js:

```
tasksController = function() {
    var taskPage;
    var initialized = false;

    return
    {
        init: function(page) {
            if(!initialized)
            {
                 .... some manipulation with jQuery...    
                initialized = true;             
            }
        }
    }
} ();
```

Back in my main .html file I call tasks controller right after body closing element:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  tasksController.init($('#taskPage'));
}
</script>
```

When I test the file, in Google chrome tools, I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( on line 8 of tasks-controller.js which is this line:

```
init: function(page)
```

along with another error that 'tasksController' is not defined when I call it above.  Any suggestions to what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: couldn't see any problem in your code.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything wrong in particular, unless there are magic spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The `ready` method is where the error is. You missed the `)` of `ready`.

See the highlighted code and comments in the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tasksController.init($('#taskPage'));
}); // The ) you've missed
// ^^^
```

Other problem in your code is the `return` statement. If you put the `object` to the next line of `return` it will always return `undefined`.
[**Automatic semicolon insertion**](http://jamesallardice.com/understanding-automatic-semi-colon-insertion-in-javascript/) will cause the code to put semicolon after `return`.

So, it'll be like `return;`.

Use following code:

```
tasksController = function() {
    var taskPage;
    var initialized = false;

    return {
        init: function(page) {
            if (!initialized) {
                ....some manipulation with jQuery...
                initialized = true;
            }
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: Um, there is one there.

Comment: @Scimonster `<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  tasksController.init($('#taskPage'));
}
</script>` Don't see in this

Comment: DownVoters, please add comments here

Comment: I think automatic semicolon insertions happens when minified. I may be wrong.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal NO! It happens for all the javascripts

Answer (score 0):

Due to implicit semicolons, your code equals this:

```
return;
{
    init: function(page) {
        if(!initialized)
        {
             .... some manipulation with jQuery...    
            initialized = true;             
        }
    }
}
```

The return is returning nothing, and so the `{}` makes a new block. Now you can see why you have a syntax error.

Just change the first line to `return {` (no newline) and you should be good.

See [Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003277/3187556).