# Perl `$[`, why base 42?

Tags: perl

I found [this part of an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature#comment1916133_1996314) really confusing. Most of the answers are special cases of some basic rules, such as the `"333" + "222" == "333222" but "333" - "222" = 111` of javascript, where using `+` for string concatenation is useful.

> `$[` — change your array base from 0-based to 1-based to 42-based: WHEEE!

What's the use case for 42-based array indexing? Just a Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy reference / incredibly evil easter egg, or actually useful?

Comment: `$[` can be used to set other bases, too; the commenter was almost certainly (a) ridiculing the "feature" and (b) making an HHGTTG reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do

```
$[ = 42
```

you set the "base" of your array indexing to 42; so the first element of an array can be requested by doing

```
$something[42]
```

instead of

```
$something[0]
```

Obviously this is immensely helpful if you want to, or you need to, or your is just that but also can't. Therefore, it [was deprecated to the ninth circle of deprecation hell](http://www.perl6.org/archive/rfc/355.html).

Comment: @ikegami: sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: Your choice to link to an essay written in support of adding `$[` to another language is interesting, though it does mention that "`$[` is not just deprecated, it is dissed" in Perl5.

Comment: If you happen to have a more precise document where `$[` gets deprecated, I'd ask you to just modify the link in my answer.

Comment: It would be in one of the .0 perldelta. I'm too exhausted to look it up right now.

Comment: [Deprecated in 5.12.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5120delta.html#Assignment-to-%24[), although there are no details beyond "Assignment to `$[`". Also documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24[) under "Deprecated and removed variables."

Comment: In [5.16](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5160delta.html) it get disabled and moved into a feature. Not sure about the deprecation warning if you turn it on. "$[ is now disabled under use v5.16 . It is part of the default feature set and can be turned on or off explicitly with use feature 'array_base' ."