# How to check if module function exist in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a module and defined functions in it. Sometimes I need to check if a certain function is actually already created.

For example

```
var newyork = function() { 
   console.log("newyork");
};

var washington = function() { 
   console.log("washington");
};

exports.newyork = newyork;
exports.washington = washington;
```

Now in the different file, I want to first check if the function exists, something like:

```
var cities = require('./city');

if(cities.newyork) {
  console.log("city function exist");
}
else {
  //false
}
```

Comment: "something like" actually works.

Comment: @JonasW. really omg?

Comment: Yes, Javascript *is* cool

Comment: @JonasW. 1) [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature#answer-1998224) 2) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature#answer-2003277) 3) [arguable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature#answer-2003942).

Comment: @alexL do you really wanna argue or ... ? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments what you wrote actually works because

```
if(cities.newyork){
```

Checks if `cities.newyork` is *truthy*. The following things are truthy:

- functions (thats why it works here)
- numbers except 0
- strings except an empty one
- objects / arrays

If it is however not defined, `cities.newyork` will be `undefined` which is *falsy* (will enter the `else` branch)

Answer (score 0):

> typeof cities.cityName === 'function'

if city's name is assigned to some variable

> typeof cities[cityName] === 'function'