# check if module method exist in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506264/how-to-check-if-module-function-exist-in-node-js/51506511#51506511) question and has a slightly different problem.

So I have a function in `cities.js` file

```
module.exports = {


    newyork: function (latitude,longitude) {
        console.log("newyork is here");
}
```

If I access this function this way `if(cities.newyork){}`then true and false condition works fine but If I access function this way

```
 var city = 'newyork';
    if(cities.city){
console.log("true");
}else{
console.log(false);
}
```

It always goes in else condition. Because cities names would be dynamic so I need this function to work. I have tried this way as well

```
if(typeof cities.city === 'function'){
      console.log("true");
    }else{
     console.log(false);
    }
```

Still no luck. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is `cities[city]`. As is, your code is looking for a property of cities literally called 'city'

Answer (score 0):

You should use, `cities[city]`. This is because,

In `cities.city`, "city" will be considered as "key name". So it will transformed as `cities["city"]`

But in `cities[city]` it will actually transform to `cities["newyork"]`

So always use, `obj[dynamic_key_name]`. Access property with `"."` only when you know the property name.