# Async-Await or Promises with JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, synchronous

I am building an application in Cordova using [Firebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase) for the database.

I have been using promises to get information back from the database and it works great, but once I get that back I usually have a series of functions that I need to call to update everything.

For example,

1. update local storage
2. call variable from local storage
3. reload page with updated storage information

I need to create/convert my JavaScript functions to be able to be called in succession.

Comment: Can you edit the question title so it reflects the question's content?

Comment: Rewrite your title

Comment: Most likely your issues stem from `updateCS()` not returning a Promise (or even if it does, you're not using it)

Comment: I don't get your explanation why you "*cant use a .then on this or place it in the .then above*". Please try it and show us that code, the approach should work.

Comment: That isn't possible. You can't cause the `return` to wait. You'll have to instead do something else, like return false by default, disable the input, then when the work is done apply the change or don't and then re-enable the input.

Comment: Don't blame the language...blame the developer

Comment: JS is the best language ever, it [has really nice features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: lul so much hate. @charlietfl why do you think I am here? I am asking because I know i can't figure it out.

Comment: @JonasWilmsI like JS i just dont get await and promises and how to use them for my needs. I've read the docs but still don't see how to apply it.

Comment: @KevinB it isn't returning a promise.

Comment: @McVenco Edited title. If you have a better option i'm all ears :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are really asking is how to implement a function after a promise is done. If so, then making the function an Async function will do the trick.

For information on async-await check out *[Async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)*.

Comment: Yeah, basically I have 8 functions that get called through out my app. Some of them need to be called in succession for the other ones to work. For example: 

update local storage variable needs to be done updating before i call that local storage variable to populate what is on the page. then once this is all done reload the page.

I read that async stuff but without a more specific example it has always been hard for me to reverse engineer.

Comment: @hefty_kat try watching youtube videos, I find them easier to understand. Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGoAdn-e5II. The concept is well explained in a simple manner.