# Is there a bitwise operation that returns 1 of the bits are equal?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am trying to write a simple C bitwise operation that returns YES if the bits are equal.
Truth table is the following:

[image]

I tried various combinations of AND,XOR and OR and no luck.
Granted, I could scan each bit pair and ask the question using an "IF" statement but rather do it more elegantly.

This is an example of what I need:

```
x = 251 - 11111011
y = 18  - 00010010
r = 22  - 00010110
```

Comment: It’s called not xor

Comment: This is `!(X ^ Y)`

Comment: I think we need to see an example input, with expected output. It's not clear whether the output is supposed to be a single boolean, or an integer value containing all the resulting bits.

Comment: its `~(X ^ Y)` which is the same as `~X ^ Y` and `X ^ ~Y`; for reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional

Comment: So if `X ^ ~Y` produces the right input then `^~` is the operator you wanted.  Kind of like the `-->` (down to) operator https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220319/2193968.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@daniel, @Barmar and @pignotto have given the answer in comments, but to make it clear for you. Make a truth table for the XOR operator (which in C would be `X ^ Y`):

| X | Y | R |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

This is the inverse of what you want - i.e. where R is `0`, you want `1` and vice-versa.

So you want `R = ~(X ^ Y)`.

The `~` operator inverts all the bits, turning `0` into `1` and `1` into `0`.

Equivalent expressions are `~X ^ Y` and `X ^ ~Y`. If `X` or `Y` is a constant or is used repeatedly where it does not vary (as in a loop), then `~X` or `~Y` could be computed in advance, leaving only XOR to be computed. (This is a minor optimization, and a modern compiler might make it automatically.)

Comment: `~X ^ Y` has the same result and should be mentioned in case `X` is constant, so `~X` can be computed at compile time (or as a loop invariant etc.), thus saving one operation at run-time. Although the compiler might recognize this anyway as part of optimization.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Please edit my answer to that effect if you wish.